# PWA Behaviour: Come to foreground

Tags: events, progressive-web-apps, schedule, foreground

Is the following behaviour possible with a PWA:

App coming to the foreground after5/15/30 minutes (scheduled) after sending app to background?

Thanks!

Comment: The user controls what app is in the foreground. If that was available to developers, some would probably take advantage of that for no good.

Comment: :-) additional info #Mathias: and goes after a short user action again into the background.
But maybe this is only a schedule action without direct system interaction?